# Status Is Set, But Still Getting TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'status')

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

So I'm working on my first Discord bot js, and I've been getting errors and following steps in other answers to solve issues.

This error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'status')" is confusing me though as I followed the steps in numerous other answers and other forums to set the status.

Maybe I'm missing something in my code?

Here's my errors:

```
/home/container/node_modules/@discordjs/collection/src/collection.ts:326
                        if (fn(val, key, this)) results.set(key, val);
       ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'status')
    at /home/container/index.js:30:78
    at _Collection.filter (/home/container/node_modules/@discordjs/collection/src/collection.ts:326:8)
    at updateChannelDescriptions (/home/container/index.js:30:45)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

And the index.js file:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: [
  Discord.GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
  Discord.GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages
]})
require('dotenv').config();

const ROLE_CHANNEL_MAP = {
    "123": "456", // Rust role and channel IDs
    "789": "987"  // 7DTD role and channel IDs
};

client.on('ready', () => {
    client.user.setActivity(`a game`, {type: 'PLAYING'});
    client.user.setPresence({status: "online"});
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
    updateChannelDescriptions();
    setInterval(updateChannelDescriptions, 300); // Updates every 5 minutes
});


async function updateChannelDescriptions() {
    for (const [roleId, channelId] of Object.entries(ROLE_CHANNEL_MAP)) {
        const role = await client.guilds.cache.first().roles.fetch(roleId);
        const channel = await client.guilds.cache.first().channels.cache.get(channelId);

        if (!role || !channel) continue;

        const membersWithRole = role.members;
        const onlineCount = membersWithRole.filter(member => member.presence.status === 'online').size;
        const newDescription = `${role.name} Role Members: ${membersWithRole.size}, Online: ${onlineCount}`;

        channel.setTopic(newDescription)
            .then(updated => console.log(`Channel ${channel.name} description updated.`))
            .catch(console.error);
    }
}

client.login(process.env.BOT_TOKEN);
```

What have I overlooked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you add a null check at finding onlinecount?

```js
const onlineCount = membersWithRole.filter(member => member.presence && member.presence.status === 'online').size;
```

Also check bot has presence intent enabled at discord developer portal, check under bot settings. That should be all.